# How do you get PowerShell to ignore blank CSV values?

Tags: powershell, active-directory, powershell-core

I'm writing a script that is supposed to update each attribute in Active Directory based on a CSV file. This is what I have so far:

```
$employees = Import-Csv -Path .\ADFieldsTest.csv
foreach ($User in $employees)
{
    $Username = $User.username
    $Department = $User.department
    $Displayname = $User.displayname
    $Fax = $User.fax
    $Manager = $User.manager
    $Mobilephone = $User.mobilephone
    $Officephone = $User.officephone
    $Title = $User.title
    $server = $User.server

    Set-ADUser -Identity $username -Department $department -DisplayName $displayname -Fax $fax -Manager $manager -MobilePhone $mobilephone -Title $title -Server $server
}
```

It kind of breaks when it reaches a cell that is blank in the CSV.
**Is there a way to get PowerShell to just pass a "null" value or something so it keeps running?**

I also tried running this with like !null values and like -nq '' but it still fails when it hits the the blank values

Comment: Why does input have blank cells?  You have to understand the root cause of issue before you can fix.  The code is doing what it is programmed to do.  Without all the required inputs it is not going to work properly.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a way of telling `Import-Csv` to not create properties for empty values, the validation has to be done in your loop. You can use [`String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(String)` Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.isnullorwhitespace?view=net-7.0) to validate and skip empty values and create a [splatting hashtable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting?view=powershell-7.3#splatting-with-hash-tables) to use with `Set-ADUser`.

Also, since your CSV columns seem to have the exact same names as the `Set-ADUser` parameters, you could avoid doing multiple `if` conditions and replace the logic with an inner loop.

```bash
foreach($User in Import-Csv -Path .\ADFieldsTest.csv) {
    if(-not [string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($User.username)) {
        # if there is no username then this line has to be skipped
        continue
    }
    
    $setSplat = @{}
    foreach($prop in $User.PSObject.Properties) {
        if([string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($prop.Value)) {
            # if the value is empty string then skip
            continue
        }
        $setSplat[$prop.Name] = $prop.Value
    }

    Set-ADUser @setSplat
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure if I did this correctly but:
https://imgur.com/a/hnZGNX2

Comment: @Shanebagel no, the code I posted as is should work. The splat is generated dynamically based on your CSV columns and values. Checking if there are empty values and `$setSplat[$prop.Name] = $prop.Value` is all you need in the inner loop

Comment: Oh wow ok I'll try running that

Comment: @Shanebagel try it with tests users first of course :)

Comment: Hmm doesn't seem to do anything, but it doesn't throw errors?

Comment: @Shanebagel mm I missed one line of code, `$setSplat = @{}` (see the update)

Comment: Hmm still doesn't do anything sorry

Comment: @Shanebagel I mean, you need to query the users again to see the updates, `Set-ADUser` doesnt produce any output unless you use `-PassThru`